# Meteor session cookie & meteor_login_token

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

According to the [docs](http://info.meteor.com/blog/session-cookies) , Meteor doesn't use session cookies.

However, what's the `meteor_login_token` cookie used for then? It looks to me like a session cookie, created after the user successfully signs in, and passed then to every request made to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meteor definitely doesn't use cookies.

Do you have any additional packages with your app that could add this cookie? For example, [fast-render](https://github.com/kadirahq/fast-render) has the ability to get data related to a user by sending the same login token using cookies.

If we take a look at [their code](https://github.com/kadirahq/fast-render/blob/master/lib/client/auth.js#L36-L41), they indeed have a function setting a cookie named `meteor_login_token`.

```
function setToken(loginToken, expires) {
  Cookie.set('meteor_login_token', loginToken, {
    path: '/',
    expires: expires
  });
}
```

This behavior is described in the [security part](https://github.com/kadirahq/fast-render/blob/master/README.md#security) of their [readme](https://github.com/kadirahq/fast-render/blob/master/README.md).

If you're not using [fast-render](https://github.com/kadirahq/fast-render), you should definitely check any additional packages you may have that could add an additional cookie.